# Slow parsing of data from db using Scan in go

Tags: postgresql, go, optimization, backend

I have this function

```
func GetDictAsset(db Connector.IDatabase) []Models.DictAsset {
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM dict_asset")
    start1 := time.Now()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    var queryResult []Models.DictAsset
    var dictAsset Models.DictAsset

    for rows.Next() {
        start := time.Now()

        err := rows.Scan(&dictAsset.ID, &dictAsset.Asset, &dictAsset.LotSize, &dictAsset.Comment, &dictAsset.TradingAbbreviation, &dictAsset.BlockchainInfo, &dictAsset.MinimalAmount)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        queryResult = append(queryResult, dictAsset)
        elapsed := time.Since(start)
        fmt.Printf("Iteration done in %s\n", elapsed)

    }
    elapsed := time.Since(start1)
    fmt.Printf("Function done in %s\n", elapsed)
    return queryResult
}
```

It works, but without time to execute query it costs 130ms
How can I make it faster? Max time of execution should me no more than 1ms (without time to execute query)
Query results in about 600 rows, with small amount of data in it

My model is

```
type DictAsset struct {
    ID                  int      `db:"id"`
    Asset               string   `db:"asset"`
    LotSize             string   `db:"lot_size"`
    Comment             *string  `db:"comment"`
    TradingAbbreviation string   `db:"trading_abbreviation"`
    BlockchainInfo      *string  `db:"blockchain_info"`
    MinimalAmount       *float32 `db:"minimal_amount"`
}
```

I tried to use reflect:

```
    for rows.Next() {
        dictAsset := Models.DictAsset{}

        s := reflect.ValueOf(&dictAsset).Elem()
        numCols := s.NumField()
        columns := make([]interface{}, numCols)
        for i := 0; i < numCols; i++ {
            field := s.Field(i)
            columns[i] = field.Addr().Interface()
        }

        err := rows.Scan(columns...)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        queryResult = append(queryResult, dictAsset)
    }
```

but it costs about the same

note: blockchain_info in db stored in jsonb format, could this be the problem?